# Armadillo Lib (C++): find operation with sparse matrix (sp_mat class)

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am trying to use the `find operator` of `armadillo` in context of `sparse matrix (class sp_mat)`.

It works fine in context of full matrix; but with the sparse matrix (`d1` in the following example)

```
            mat  A  = randu<mat>(5,5);
            mat  B  = randu<mat>(5,5);
            uvec q2 = find(A != 0.5);

            uvec q1 = find(d1 != -0.5);   // d1 is a sparse matrix; ERROR REPORTED HERE
```

I get the following error:

```
Error   3   error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'arma::sp_mat' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Could someone suggest how could I perform find operation?

and

Also, if there is a way to convert sparse matrix (class sp_mat) to full matrix (class mat)? I tried to use "conv_to" without any success.

Answer (score 4):

How to convert a sparse matrix to a dense matrix:

```
sp_mat A;
A.sprandu(20, 20, 0.1);

mat B(A);
B.print("B:");
```

The constructor for the `mat` class can take a sparse matrix as input, as listed in the [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat).